# "Reason to visit" or "Reason for visit"

Tags: prepositions

> "Reason to visit" or "Reason for visit" ?

Which one is correct grammatically?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the difference is that we use "to" when "visit" is a verb:

> I can't think of a single reason to visit them.

and "for" when "visit" is a noun:

> And what was the reason for their visit?

Of course, when "visit" is a noun, you will need to add an article before it (*Get ready for the visit*), a determiner (*I am not ready for that visit*) or a possessive pronoun like in the example.

If you want to use it without a modifier, then you can do as J.R suggested and turn it into a gerund.

Answer (score 14):

Interestingly enough, I would use *to* with *visit*, but *for* when using *visiting*:

> The nightlife – that’s the reason ***to*** visit Paris!
>
> The nightlife – that’s the reason ***for*** visiting Paris!

The phrase *to visit* acts as an infinitive, but we use *for* when switching to the gerund form:

> Our neighbors are welcome to come over anytime; they don't need a good reason **to visit**.
>
> Our neighbors are welcome to come over anytime; they don't need a good reason **for visiting**.

Either of those sounds fine to me (and I'm lucky to have such good neighbors).

This isn't something unique to the word *visit*; many other verbs work the same way when paired with *reason*:

> If you like organic foods, that's a good **reason to shop** at a local farmer's market.
>
> If you like organic foods, that's a good **reason for shopping** at a local farmer's market.

Comment: When going through customs: "What is the reason for your visit?"

Comment: @Doc - Good point. If you add a qualifier (_your, the, a_, etc.) then all bets are off on the preposition. _"When we arrived at his office, he wanted to know **the reason_ of _our visit**"_ (Frieda Lefeber, _Frieda's Journey_, 2003).

Answer (score 5):

"Reason for visit" is not *quite* grammatically correct.  Consider these phrases:

- **reason for visiting**

  … as in "Do you have a reason for visiting your doctor?"
- **reason for your visit**

  Once you are there, the receptionist might as, "What is the reason for your visit today?"
- **reason for visit**

  Alternatively, the reception might ask you to fill out a questionnaire that contains a field labelled "Reason for visit?"  Such a field would be acceptable on a form, as it is understood to mean one of the two phrases above, with some words omitted to save space.  However, you could never use "reason for visit" in a proper sentence, since *visit* is a noun that is missing an article or adjective.

Note that there is a difference in meaning between *reason to visit* and *reason for visiting*.  The former can apply only to a visit that has not yet taken place.  Therefore, in the examples above, the receptionist or the questionnaire could not ask "What is your reason to visit the doctor today?" since you are already there.

Comment: I have a question in your last paragraph. I think the receptionist might ask it before the patient actually sees the doctor. So if we regard "visit" as the action in the same room with the doctor, isn't "reason to visit" also okay?

Comment: @SmartHumanism No, a receptionist would also not use "reason to visit", which is more about making plans to see the doctor. By the time the patient has arrived at the clinic, "reason for visiting" would be the phrase to use.

Comment: So do you mean, the second the patient takes one's foot in the clinic, the patient is already "visit"ing? I was wondering if "visit" can be regarded as an action of "coming into the doctor's room" in a narrow respect of meaning.

Comment: @SmartHumanism The choice of "for" vs. "to" is not so much about time or location. Rather, a "reason to …" is about motivation (why you _want_ to do something), and a "reason for …" is about justification (explaining why an action is/was correct).

Comment: Okay, I got it. But, I think the example you mentioned can be a little bit controversial. Anyways, I have got your point and I appreciate your answers. It was helpful. Thank you!